# how to store this data in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have table -> interests_cats

```
id - category
1  -  Music
2  -  Fashion
3  -  Movies
```

and interests table

```
id - interest - cat_id
1  - Inception - 3
2  - Jackson   - 1
3  - Ralf      - 2
```

and the user form I have like this

```
Fashion   [  ] [  ] [   ]
Music     [  ] [  ] [   ]
Movies    [  ] [  ] [   ]
```

[    ] -> text input
,I'm using PHP

how can I receive and store the data from the form ?

Comment: We don't build it for -- what have you tried?

Comment: What the thisrd table is about ?

Comment: @OMG Ponies I tried the html array but the problem is the interests categories are dynamic so I don't think it a good way to go .

Comment: @bensiu: I reckon the 3rd is the form where the user enters the data, not a table

Comment: @bensiu it's not a table , it's the user form structure where the user can put his interests .

Comment: is it 3 columns because 3 position in interest table or just coinsidence ?

Comment: I advice you to use PDO to make it safe => http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can generate your form like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id, category FROM categories ORDER BY category");
while (mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
      echo $res['category'];
      for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
          echo " <input name='cat_" . $res["id"] . "_" . $i . "' />"; 
      }
```

So you will have the fields named `cat_1_1`, `cat_1_2`, `cat_1_3`, `cat_2_1`, ..., `cat_3_3`

In the page where you process the form you just need to split by `_`, fetch the 2nd token (the category id, you can discard the rest) and put the values in the DB, one by one.

So for instance (may need some additional tweaking/error checking etc.):

```
foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
      {
      $tokens = preg_split("/_/", $name);
      if ($tokens[0] == "cat")
          {
          $catnum = (int)$tokens[1];
          // INSERT ($catnum, $value) in the table here.
          }
      }
```

Comment: can you please illustrate how to process the variables ? how can I know for example that there is $_POST['cat_5_1'] ?

Comment: it's may be late , but when I generate the form I want to put the values in the form from the interests table , how can I do this ?

Comment: @Waseem Abu Senjer: In the for loop add another query like `SELECT interest FROM tablename WHERE cat_id= $i`. You can then just set the `value` attribute of the `input` tag with the value read in such way! You may have to account for the fact that you will not always have 3 values in the table, in that case add an empty `input`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fashion   [ Diore ] [  ] [   ] 
Music     [  ] [  ] [   ] 
Movies    [ Robin Hood ] [ Avatar ] [   ]
```

if music [1] not null -> INSERT ( 'Robin Hood', 3 (music) ) -> else do nothing, where music should indexed to 3

Comment: What if I fill only the 2nd field? Never ever assume the user will do things the way your website was intended to work!

Comment: you looping in (3) columns and proceed when is not null

Comment: Yes, but you're only checking whether music[1] is not null, which won't work.

Comment: it is your program you checking want you want - I give you idea